# fopen não abre arquivos vindos de upload

Tags: php

Colegas.

Estou precisando popular uma tabela com um arquivo CSV e estou usando um código simples em PHP/Mysql para isso. Porém mesmo com a permissão 755 no arquivo, não consigo. Ele diz que não foi possível encontrar o arquivo. Segue o código:

```
// PHP
 if($_POST){            
           $arquivo = $_FILES['Arquivo']['name'];
           $arquivoTemp = $_FILES['Arquivo']['tmp_name'];
           $diretorio = "arquivo/".$arquivo;
           move_uploaded_file($arquivoTemp, $diretorio);
           $abrirArquivo = fopen(basename($_FILES['Arquivo']['tmp_name']), "r");

           if (!$abrirArquivo){
               echo "arquivo não encontrado!"; // Ele para aqui!
            }else{
                while ($valores = fgetcsv ($abrirArquivo, 2048, ";")) {
                       //aqui faço a inserção
                }
            }
        }

// HTML
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table width="500px" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="file" name="Arquivo"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Enviar"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

Comment: Você tem algum debug tipo? Xdebug? coloca o caminho do arquivo fixo em uma variável para testar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está usando o **fopen** com o caminho do arquivo temporário, que já foi movido pelo **move_uploaded_file**.

Tente fazer essa alteração no código:

```
<?php
 if($_POST){            
           $arquivo = $_FILES['Arquivo']['name'];
           $arquivoTemp = $_FILES['Arquivo']['tmp_name'];
           $diretorio = "arquivo/".$arquivo;
           move_uploaded_file($arquivoTemp, $diretorio);
           $abrirArquivo = fopen($diretorio, "r");

           if (!$abrirArquivo){
               echo "arquivo não encontrado!"; // Ele para aqui!
            }else{
                while ($valores = fgetcsv ($abrirArquivo, 2048, ";")) {
                       //aqui faço a inserção
                }
            }
        }
?>
```